# how to make options based on the current year

Tags: javascript, html, select

I want to have options of this year and next year, but I can't figure out how to integrate the JavaScript variable into the `value = ""` and the text inside the option tags. This code demonstrates what I mean (obviously it is not valid, but shows what I mean). so today the first option would be 2013 and the next, 2014. Thanks.

```
var date = new Date(),
y = date.getFullYear();

<html>
  <select id = "year">
      <option value = "y" >y</option>
      <option value = "(y + 1)">(y + 1)</option>
  </select>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: yes, most of the script is jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you're using jQuery, you can use this:

```
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
var opts;
$('#year').append(function () {
    for (var i = currentYear; i <= currentYear + 1; i++) {
        opts += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
    }
    return opts;
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LsyLa/)**

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
var sel = $("#year"),
    date = new Date(),
    y = date.getFullYear(),
    newOptions = "";
newOptions += "<option value='" + y + "'>" + y + "</option>";
newOptions += "<option value='" + (y + 1) + "'>" + (y + 1) + "</option>";
sel.append(newOptions);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YxqcT/

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery. Simple HTML DOM can do the work for you.
Sample >> http://jsfiddle.net/47dDu/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="MySelectBox">
<option value="1" id="this_year"></option>
<option value="2" id="next_year"></option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();

var x = document.getElementById("this_year");
x.innerHTML=d.getFullYear(); //get this year

var y = document.getElementById("next_year");
y.innerHTML=d.getFullYear()+1; //get next year
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a nice pure Js option, however it does not define the value as the year. Thank you for the answer, +1